# How to choose what implementation get's injected in to an autowired constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control, autowired

Say I have an interface

```
interface IPerson {...}
```

I have two implementations of this interface

```
@Component
class Programmer implements IPerson {...}

@Component
class LionTamer implements IPerson {...}
```

Say I have a class that uses Autowire injection

```
@Component
class SomethingThatDoesStuff { 

    @Autowired
    public SomethingThatDoesStuff (IPerson someone) {
        ...
    }

}
```

How does Spring know what implementation to inject? Is there a way to tell spring what implementation to inject? Can this be done via the annotation or do I have to define some sort of factory? If so how?

Comment: `@qualifier` will do

Comment: If you run the above code, ideally you will get a Spring initialisation error as it two implementations for the interface. As mentioned in above comment, you can add qualifier names for two implementations and inside @Autowire you can mention the qualifier name.

Comment: This is a duplicate

Comment: @RolsonQuadras can you post an answer with a code example?

Comment: if you qualify and choose one in the `SomethingThatDoesStuff`, isn't that the same as not using constructor di at all? I mean I guess you could still make use of it in tests, but for the code, if you need to change which one, either way you would need to update the dependency in the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @passion mentioned, you should use bean naming ([standard Spring IoC feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)):

```
@Component("programmer")
class Programmer implements IPerson {...}

@Component("lionTamer")
class LionTamer implements IPerson {...}

@Component
class SomethingThatDoesStuff { 

    @Autowired
    public SomethingThatDoesStuff (@Qualifier("programmer") IPerson someone) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be more elegant to just require Programmer type in the signature of SomethingThatDoesStuff constructor?

Comment: Maybe, but in this case you probably want to take advantage of polymorphism IPerson provides. Why otherwise would use have that interface in place?

Comment: Would be cool if you can pass a class type and not just a string